# Lower bounds for pattern complexity of aperiodic subshifts

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, symbolic-dynamics

In the setting of symbolic dynamics over $\mathbb{Z}^d$, one can define for the $n$-th pattern complexity of a given a subshift $\Omega\subseteq \mathcal{A}^{\mathbb{Z}^d}$ as

$$ c_n(\Omega):= \Big\vert \{P\in \mathcal{A}^{Q_n}: P= \omega\vert_{Q_n} \; \text{for some} \; \omega\in \Omega \} \Big\vert $$

with $Q_n:=\{0,...,n-1\}^d$. I know by Morse-Hedlund theorem that if $d=1$ and $\Omega$ contains an aperiodic configuration $\omega\in \mathcal{A}^{\mathbb{Z}}$, then $c_n(\Omega)\geq n+1$ for all $n$. I  found [this recent paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.00784.pdf), stating that if $d=2$ and $\Omega$ has an aperiodic configuration, then $c_n(\Omega)\geq n^2+1$.

I was trying to find what is known in general dimensions $d\geq 3$? I am actually interested whether a weaker version of this sort of claim holds. i.e., if there exists a constant $C_d>0$, such that $\Omega\subseteq \mathcal{A}^{\mathbb{Z}^d}$ is a subshift containing an aperiodic configuration implies that $c_n(\Omega)\geq C_d \cdot n^d$?

I am assuming this might be more commonly referred to in a terminology I am not aware of, but I assume that this should be known. Does anyone know of a work or survey in this direction for general $d$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no in a very strong sense: there does not exist such $C_d$ for $d \geq 3$ even for aperiodic minimal subshifts.

As far as finding lower bounds goes, complexities of subshifts containing aperiodic configurations are more or less the same as complexities of individual aperiodic configurations, namely a subshift containing aperiodic $x$ has at least the complexity of $x$, and conversely an aperiodic $x$ will have orbit closure with exactly the complexity of $x$.

In
https://eventos.cmm.uchile.cl/sdynamics20208/wp-content/uploads/sites/111/2021/01/cassaigne.pdf
Julien Cassaigne attributes to Lagarias and Peasants the conjecture that $\limsup_n c_n(x)/n^d > \infty$ for any $d$-dimensional aperiodic configuration $x$, i.e. that your $C_d$ would exist in the lim sup sense, and to Lagarias, Peasants, Sander and Tijdeman the result that there exists an $x$ with $\liminf_n c_n(x)/n^d = 0$, i.e. your $C_d$ does not exist in the lim inf sense. I did not follow up on the references.

He then proves the following theorem:

> Theorem. Let $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ tend to infinity. Then for any $d \geq 3$ there exists an aperiodic uniformly recurrent $d$-dimensional configuration $x \in A^{\mathbb{Z}^d}$ such that $c_n(x) = O(n^2 f(n))$.

In particular the orbit closure is a minimal subshift where all configurations are aperiodic and the complexity is as above. He leaves open whether $O(n^2)$ complexity is possible in dimension $d \geq 3$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for. Does this theorem show that the conjecture by Lagarias and Pleasents is false, by taking $f= o(n^{d-2})$? In the slides you linked to the function was just real valued, which would allow this. But since he doesn't explicitly state this, I am assuming that this is not true.

Comment: Yes, Cassaigne precisely disproves the conjecture of Lagarias and Pleasants. "Our goal is to further improve it to obtain $\lim_n \frac{P(n)}{n^d} = 0$ [where $P(n) = c_n(x)$], and thus disprove the above conjecture [of Lagarias and Pleasants]."

Comment: Okay, I guess I'm not sure about what I am reading without it being stated very explicitly. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 7):

There are a few things to clarify here.

First of all, the two-dimensional version of Morse-Hedlund, i.e. that whenever $X$ contains a point with no period vector, $p_{m,n}(X) \geq mn+1$ holds for all $m,n$, is called the **Nivat conjecture**, and is still open!

There has been huge progress recently, including a wonderful paper of Kari-Moutot, which proves that if $X$ has ONLY aperiodic points, then for all $m,n$, $p_{m,n}(X) \geq mn+1$. This also implies that if $X$ is minimal, i.e. the orbit closure of any of its points, then Nivat holds. But it leaves open the possible case that $X$ has an aperiodic configuration whose orbit closure contains periodic configurations, and that $p_{m,n}(X) \leq mn$ for all $m,n$.

The paper you referenced proves Nivat for a subclass of subshifts defined by substitutions; there are a few papers proving special cases like this, including another paper by Kari and Moutot which relates Nivat to some so-called algebraic subshifts (see Ville's comment below), but does not provide a complete resolution.

I should mention two other partial Nivat results. The first is by Kari and Szabados, and proves that if $X$ contains an aperiodic configuration, there are at most finitely many $m,n$ so that $p_{m,n}(X) \leq mn$; this uses Hilbert's Nullstellensatz! The second is by Cyr and Kra, who proved that if you replace $mn$ by $mn/2$, then Nivat holds (i.e. if $X$ has an aperiodic configuration, then $p_{m,n}(X) > mn/2$ for all $m,n$.

As far as $d > 2$, the general consensus is that Nivat-type results are false. Indeed, consider a configuration $x$ in $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{Z}^3}$ which is $0$ except for two biinfinite lines of $1$s which are non-parallel and do not intersect (for instance, $x(i,j,k) = 1$ iff $i, j = 0$ or $i, k = 10$), and take $X$ to be the orbit closure of $x$. Then $x$ is aperiodic, and yet it's not hard to check that for large $n$, $p_{n,n,n}(X) \approx C n^2$.

There is an annoying point here; even though $x$ is not technically periodic, it certainly feels 'almost periodic' in a sense. There is a paper by Durand and Rigo which pursues this idea, showing that if complexity is low for ANY $d$, then the points of $X$ are `simple' in the sense of being describable in something called the Presburger arithmetic. I'm not aware of any other progress for $d > 2$.

Comment: Doesn't the Kari-Szabados result sayThe existence of an aperiodic point implies that $p_{m,n}(X) \geq mn+1$ for some (even almost all) $m,n$, contrary to the claim in your first paragraph?

Comment: Also I think it's not true that Nivat has been shown for algebraic subshifts. Rather it's known that the Nivat assumption implies that the configuration belongs to an algebraic subshift, and then we know that some algebraic subshifts cannot appear.

Comment: I was virtually positive when writing this that (a) I would make mistakes and (b) that you specifically would catch them :) Thanks, and I will go back and update the answer.

Comment: Heh. Note that Kari-Szabados also gives you another sense in which the two-lines example is periodic: Every configuration that satisfies the Nivat assumption is a finite sum of periodic configurations (in general they need to be over infinite alphabets, but in the case of two lines they are not).

Comment: (I upvoted your comment mentioning me so that it doesn't look like I've upvoted your comment mentioning me.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was not sure about the strict inequality I wrote, but the motivation to my question was the estimates by Cyr and Kra. I was interested in whether we can say that $\liminf \frac{c_n(\Omega)}{n^d}>0$?

Comment: Certainly not for literally aperiodic configurations, since the "skew lines" example I gave in 3 dimensions is on the order of $n^2$, not $n^3$. 

I personally think there is some version of aperiodicity which does imply what you wrote, but the only such result I know is what Ville mentioned; the Kari-Szabados paper proves a sense in which $c_{n} \leq n^d$ for any $n$ implies that all $x \in X$ are the sum of finitely many periodic configurations. The snag is that they're possibly on infinite alphabet(s). But that means "not sum of periodic configs on inf alphabets" implies your liminf = 1.