# 'Trivial' lower bounds for pattern complexity of aperiodic subshifts

Tags: co.combinatorics, ds.dynamical-systems, symbolic-dynamics

I recently asked in [this thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434320/lower-bounds-for-pattern-complexity-of-aperiodic-subshifts) about lower bounds on the complexity in the case where we have an aperiodic subshift. If I denote $c_n(\Omega)$ as the number of possible patterns on $Q_n= \big\{ 0,...,n-1 \big \}^d$, Ville Salo mentioned a paper\slides by Julien Cassaigne showing contrary to what I thought. Namely, that for $d\geq 3$ and any $f:\mathbb{N}\to \infty$ satisfying $\lim f(n)=\infty$, we have some aperiodic subshift $\Omega_f\subseteq \mathcal{A}^{\mathbb{Z}^d}$, such that

$$ c_n(\Omega_f)=O(n^2 f).  $$

I was hoping that $\liminf \frac{c_n(\Omega)}{n^d}\geq C_d$. My subsequent question is whether we can say for $d\geq 3$, that for an aperiodic subshift, $\Omega\subseteq \mathcal{A}^{\mathbb{Z}^d}$, we have

$$ \liminf \frac{c_n(\Omega)}{n^2}\geq C_d \quad \text{or even} \quad \liminf \frac{c_n(\Omega)}{n}\geq C_d  .$$

It seems to me that this should be true if we take an aperiodic configuration $\omega \in \mathcal{A}^{\mathbb{Z}^d}$ and project them to a $2$-dimensional or $1$-dimensional subspaces by the standard basis this should work. i.e., one of these projected configurations would have to be aperiodic and we can use the results in the $2$/$1$-dimensional cases.

Since I am not well versed in the subject of complexity estimations and my intuition has already been wrong, I thought that there may be a fault in this logic or a known counter-example. I would appreciate any comments on whether this question should have an obvious answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll try to do three dimensions for simplicity. I am on the bus and have to be very quick.

> Theorem. Suppose $X \subset A^{\mathbb{Z}^3}$ is a subshift, such that $\liminf_n \frac{P(n)}{n^2} = 0$. Then every point in $X$ is periodic.

Lou look at two-dimensional slices of your configuration, and use (for example) the Cyr-Kra bound $P(n) < \frac{n^2}{2} \implies \mbox{periodic}$. We get that the horizontal double slice subshift $Y = \{x|_{\mathbb{Z^2} \times \{0, 1\}} \;|\; x \in X\} \subset (A^2)^{\mathbb{Z}^2}$ has only periodic configurations.

Now we recall a result from [1]:

> Theorem. If $Y$ is a two-dimensional subshift with only periodic points, then $Y$ is a finite union of subshifts $Y_i$ such that for some nonzero vector $v_i$, $Y_i$ is globally fixed by the $v_i$-translation.

In particular the horizontal double slice subshift $Y$ has this form, so in any configuration, all the double slices have one of finitely many periods $v_1, ..., v_n$. If this period never changes, we are done. Otherwise, we get a doubly periodic slice (of height one).

Now apply the same argument to slices in another direction; now we have w.l.o.g. that the horizontal slice through the origin (the plane where z-coordinate = 0) is doubly periodic, and another slice $S$ (say y-coordinate = 0) is also.

Now, if you look at any "z-coordinate = n" slice, it actually must have period parallel to S: either this holds directly for its period, or we can move to the doubly periodic slice S along its period, move in the direction parallel to S, and go back.

So the entire point is periodic in a direction parallel to $S$. Square.

Reference(s):

[1] Anael Grandjean, Benjamin Hellouin de Menibus, Pascal Vanier

Comment: The slice $S$ should be thick enough to catch periods of the horizontal slices (for whose lengths we have a uniform bound), but I ran out of time. May try to clarify later.

Comment: Thank you for your answer (again). I understand that the idea is to look at slices and then to show if all the slice are periodic for the whole thing to be periodic. I didn't quite get what you meant about the thickness and your penultimate paragraph. When dealing with slices and using aperiodicty, aren't you essentially changing the alphabets to be a $k$-tuple, where $k$ is the thickness?

Comment: Also, I don't see why you can move to the doubly periodic slice and back?

Comment: Yeah first I use thinkness 2, and then for S the thickness depends on the period vectors we got in the first step.

Comment: So, suppose S is a thick slice with double period. In the z=n-slice called say T you have a period. If this period is not parallel to S (i.e. the direction v common to S and T), then starting anywhere on T you can move along the T-period to the slice S, say by offset w. S has a double period so you can move in direction v without the symbol changing, so you stay on T and thus can go back with -w.

Comment: I have been trying to understand some of your statements which I am not clear on, but still cannot manage. (1) What does height one mean for a slice? (2) When you say $S$ is thick enough, do you mean as thick as the maximal period? (3) It seems to me that $T$ and $Y$ slices should have mutual double periods and same thickness. I don't understand why you can implicitly assume this? (4) When you say parallel to $S$, do you mean also perpendicular to $Y$ and $T$?

Comment: (1) In general, the contents of $\mathbb{Z}^2 \times \{i, i+1, ..., i+k+1\}$ is a slice of height $k$ (...which is at height $i$).  The double slice subshift contains the slices of height $2$ (which can occur simultaneously on the planes at heights $0, 1$ equivalently at any two consecutive heights). Probably I should've said "thickness $k$" instead of "height $k$", since height refers to both value of z-coordinate and an interval of z-coordinates.

Comment: (2) yes, that is what I mean

Comment: (3) The contents of $T$ is an element of $Y$, so inherits one of $Y$'s global periods.

Comment: (4) What do you mean perpendicular to $Y$ and $T$? I am talking about a period we see on $T$, so how could it be perpendicular to $T$? So no, I do not mean also perpendicular to $Y$ and $T$. There is only one direction (up to scaling) on the affine plane defined by $T$ which is parallel to the plane $S$.

Comment: Aside from point (4) I think I understood all the other points. If I am not mistaken, we want to find global periods in all directions. Are you taking the periods you obtain for the $x$ and $z$ directions from the $S$-slice, and trying to find a period in the $y$-direction? And that's why you're looking for a period parallel to $S$?

Comment: We want to find a _single_ period for the three-dimensional configuration. It will be in the x-direction, where T uses directions x, y and S uses directions x, z. We will start at some point in T, and if the period of T is not x-directional, we can move along the period by some offset $w$, to get to the slice S, then move in direction x (because S is doubly periodic), and then go back by $-w$.

Comment: (Once we have a single global period, we can of course immediately conclude that there is a second one, again by applying e.g. the Cyr-Kra bound.)

Comment: So when we say periodic configuration, do we mean at least one period vector, or strongly periodic? Also, by definition of the slices wouldn't any period that keeps you in the slice be a global period for the whole subshift? Thanks again for the patience and sorry for the hassle.

Comment: As far as I can tell, "periodic configuration" means there is a single period, in everything I wrote above. "Also, by definition of the slices wouldn't any period that keeps you in the slice be a global period for the whole subshift?" I don't know why the period of a single slice in a single configuration would be a global period for the whole subshift. If the slice subshift has a global period, that would be a global period of the $\mathbb{Z}^3$-subshift, as well. But Cyr-Kra doesn't give that, only periodicity of individual configurations.

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't had time to rewrite the thing more carefully, hopefully we are converging with me quickly answering your questions. If you like you can send me an email or something, based on how much spam I get it shouldn't be hard to find.